# Is getnameinfo memory leaking confirmed?

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, network-programming

As per question, I'm running into some memory leaking by *getnameinfo*. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (Linux scv 3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 17:42:16 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) with gcc *version 4.6.3*.
I'm linking my server executable with *g++* and so far valgrind hasn't reported an issue. I've then added a simple call to *getnameinfo* to print out what are the network name and port of connecting clients.
And I get the following:

```
==4425== 
==4425== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4425==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==4425==   total heap usage: 4,508 allocs, 4,507 frees, 134,939,153 bytes allocated
==4425== 
==4425== 10 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==4425==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4425==    by 0x50D7D71: strdup (strdup.c:43)
==4425==    by 0x1484B861: ???
==4425==    by 0x515B871: gethostbyaddr_r@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (getXXbyYY_r.c:256)
==4425==    by 0x5161D06: getnameinfo (getnameinfo.c:223)
==4425==    by 0x404175: solsrv_run (solsrv.c:381)
==4425==    by 0x404DAC: main (main.c:167)
==4425== 
==4425== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4425==    definitely lost: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==4425==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4425==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4425==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4425==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4425== 
==4425== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4425== ERROR SUMMARY: 12 errors from 11 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Code is simply as follows:

```
struct sockaddr addr;
socklen_t           addr_sz = sizeof(addr);
char        host[NI_MAXHOST],
            serv[NI_MAXSERV];
int infd = accept(srv_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addr_sz);
if (infd == -1) {
    ... manage error on accept ...
}
if(getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&addr, addr_sz, host, NI_MAXHOST, serv, NI_MAXSERV, NI_NUMERICSERV)) {
    strncpy(host, "<unknown host>", NI_MAXHOST-1);
    strncpy(serv, "<unknown port>", NI_MAXSERV-1);
}
```

And there you have the leak...
I can confirm, that the leak is **happening**: for 6 clients connected *valgrind* found 60 bytes leaked (I guess the clients were connecting from the same host so if it's related to host name the growth is linear as expected).
Any idea?

Cheers

Comment: Could always download the source and look at what it is doing.

Comment: And since it's open source you can fix the problem yourself!

Comment: Does valgrind have this wrong? `gethostbyaddr_r@@GLIBC_2.2.5` would suggest glibc v2.2.5, no? According to http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/ that version is from around 2002.

Comment: Finding sources of 'getXXbyYY_r.c' is quite complex in the sense that the file is a huge macro... :-S And as you're suggesting, how on earth are we linking to that old GLIBC?

Comment: A couple of things: I've seend Valgrind reporting some invalid mem read/write during the first call to getnameinfo . Secondly I tried compile Valgrind 3.8.1 and run it but it gets stuck sometimes so is not really usable... probably should I extend the question with first invalid read/writes?

Comment: Probably the best way to get a precise and authoritive answer is to post this report to glibc bugzilla http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/

Comment: Raised: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14984

Comment: "*... probably should I extend the question with first invalid read/writes?*" This surely would be interesting to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually found the *real* leak.

When connecting to the server socket use `name.local` instead of `localhost` and/or the fully qualified name.
`getnameinfo()` will then leak.

I can reproduce the bug on `12.04`, `12.10` both *x64* and *x86*.
If I connect specifying `.local` on the name it leaks.

Cheers